# What is the real meaning of "literally"?

Tags: meaning

I think that some people misuse this word, and I cannot understand what it really means.

Comment: You've tagged this as "meaning-in-context" but you have not provided any context.

Comment: The "real meaning" of a word (if that means anything at all) is "what the word is used and understood to mean", not "what the word used to mean" or "what some self-appointed pundits say the word means", or even "what XYZ dictionary says the word means".

Comment: This could be answered with a dictionary search. If you've tried that already, please tell us what you've found, and perhaps some examples where you don't understand the meaning

Answer (score 1):

It used to mean only "really" or "actually" but has since taken on an additional more ephemeral meaning of "figuratively".. The meaning-in-context depends entirely upon that context.

Comment: Many people are really unhappy about this additional meaning. I am one of them. I think people who use it sound stupid.

Comment: @Michael Harvey: Note, however, that it is not exactly new. Take a look at https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/misuse-of-literally

Comment: It should mean exactly "not figuratively", so the new development is unfortunate.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey words coming to mean the opposite of what they originally meant, or close to it, is pretty common, it seems.  "Comprise" and "ancestor" come to mind (but not "cleave").

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty however unfortunate it may be, it is not particularly new.

Answer (score 0):

Many people use it incorrectly as a joke. It's a way to put emphasis on something in a silly way. Someone who says "my head is literally exploding" in regard to a headache is trying to both complain about a headache without being too whiny and also convey that the headache is awful.

Comment: Some people use it like this without joking and without realizing that their use of "literally" is inconsistent with the literal meaning of "literally."